# in what is believed to be

Tags: grammar

> A 77-year-old Australian man was killed this weekend by a kangaroo **in what is believed to be** the country’s first fatal kangaroo attack in over 80 years.

I wonder how the preposition in ( in what is believed to be...) is used in the sentence above.
In another word, I cannot understand the structure of the phrase, in what is believed to be.

Comment: Do you understand the use of "what"? Do you understand the use of the passive voice in "is believed to be"?

Comment: I know the passive voice ' is believed to be" but I wnonder why the preposition "in" is necessary in front of what.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for what prepositions go with what verbs are somewhat arbitrary.

With the passive of “kill,” the preposition “in” is often used to describe a type of situation in which people are sometimes or always killed. For example

> He was killed in an automobile accident.

This is standard English. It describes the general situation in which the death occurred.

> An Australian man was killed by a kangaroo in the first fatal kangaroo attack in over 80 years.

This is just a somewhat more complex example of this standard usage “be killed in.”

In your sentence, the “what is believed to be” is qualifying the claim that this was the first fatal kangaroo attack in over 80 years.

Answer (score 0):

The job of prepositions is to connect a noun phrase to the rest of a sentence. The preposition "in" is necessary here because without it, we have a clause followed by a noun phrase, and nothing to connect them together.

The noun phrase, "*what is believed to be the country’s first fatal kangaroo attack in over 80 years*" is the object of the preposition "in", which connects it to the main clause, "*A 77-year-old Australian man was killed this weekend by a kangaroo*".

Here's a simpler version of that sentence:

> A 77-year-old Australian man was killed this weekend in the country’s first fatal kangaroo attack in over 80 years.

The preposition "in" has the function of connecting the details of an event with the event itself. "In" *collocates* with events.